# How to deal with not yet translated texts of Hinduism?

Tags: discussion

Sanathana dharma got lot and lot of scriptures.

Lot of authentic scriptures are in many different languages. But for our [main site](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/) English is the only language to communicate.

Many texts are not yet translated in to English from many other languages. **But the answers for a lot of questions asked in our main site may lies in such not yet translated texts.**

Users are also proficient in their own languages. If the scripure is not written in their own languages, then they are totally dependent on the translated works (into English of their own language). If there is no such translated work then the user cannot able to get the answer for such questions on our main site and the [list of unanswered questions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/unanswered) obviously get increase in the site which affects the quality of the site.

Then my doubt is that how to deal with the scriptures that are **not yet available** in English which are main sources for answering?

Comment: Translate based on your knowledge or find a translated work and then answer based on that. What else are we looking for? How is this a meta discussion? How will presence of a translation of a work affect our site's running?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma  **How will presence of a translation of a work affect our site's running**

Because all of the users are not proficient in more languages and hence cannot able to answer the questions present in the scriptures that are not yet translated to his/her languages.

Comment: I still don't get your question. If there is a work, some might use the translation. We never force to use a single translation or scriptural work. We recommend it and encourage. Even if there is a translation, there might be mistakes and difference personal choice. So, doesn't affect either.There is no rule that one should be proficient in more languages. Who knows the language can understand and write answers based on own knowledge. It is as simple as that. But how is this affecting the running main site? We are okay with non published works till now. Why is this a problem now?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma What if no translation and no knowledge on language in which scripture is written?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma The user has to learn the language and then translate slokhas by himself and then to answer the questions?

Comment: Yeah. How else, if there is no translation, what is the site going to offer? Allowing translations is messy actually. Translating books is a work for a translation site. There are 2 ways 1. Find a translation offline or online and write answer 2. Translate yourselves. Each user can speak different languages but we should not allow or disallow some topic because of some users. E.g If I know Telugu, we can't allow Telugu translation questions. It should be done keeping everyone in mind.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Seems true. But difficult procedure.